# Criteria for being an effective pseudo-random generator

Tags: c++, random, generator

I implemented a class that takes two (random) `uint32_t` values, and generates pseudo-random `uint64_t` numbers with a period of 2^64 - 1. I generated 500,000,000 numbers and I could see that:

- Each percentile of [0; 2^64 - 1] was populated by 1% of all numbers, with a 10^-8 precision at least.
- For k in [2; 101], the proportion of numbers divisible by k was 1/k, with a 10^-4 precision at least, 10^-5 for a majority of them.
- No two numbers had the same value.

Are these criteria enough to say that my generator is a "good" one?

Comment: Do you want it to be cryptographically secure?

Comment: No two numbers having the same value is a bad thing for a good rng, not a good thing.

Comment: Random number test suite - https://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php

Comment: Given that 500,000,000 numbers were generated, and given that there are 2^64  possible values (which is a much greater number), I would have thought that this was a good thing? As opposed to 100 matches or more.

Comment: @pippin do you *intend* to produce a sequence of 500M with no repeats, or was that a chance of this one run you did?

Comment: @Aplet123 According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem using the formula `sqrt(2*2^64*ln(2))` you'd expect to have to generate 5 billion numbers before you get duplicates

Comment: I do agree that `No two numbers having the same value` shouldn't be a goal for a RNG but the valid goal of `The same number not being generated more often than the probability would lead you to expect` leads to the same result if your set of generated numbers is significantly smaller than the possible range of numbers.

Comment: @JohnFilleau no that wasn't my intent, but so far I have never found a single duplicate in any bench of 500,000,000 numbers.

Comment: @Pippin I calculated that you would need 340 runs of 500M uniform random numbers from a set of 2^64 possible numbers to have a 90% chance of at least one run having duplicate numbers. How long does it take you to run your generator? Although at that point you're just doing one tiny benchmark when you can take the advice above and use some prewritten benchmarks. After 148 runs of 500M numbers you'd expect to see one with duplicates.

Comment: *Are these criteria enough to say that my generator is a "good" one?* No. Firstly, there are tests that find bad ones, but passing those tests does not mean you have a good one. Secondly, different applications require different qualities. What is good for one application is useless for another. Thirdly, if this is a PRNG then statistical tests are no substitute for direct analysis of the PRNG algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

> Are these criteria enough to say that my generator is a "good" one?

There are well established tests to run and verify your PRNG:

- [TestU01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestU01) by prof L’Ecuyer
- [PractRand](http://pracrand.sourceforge.net/)
- [DieHard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) by prof. Marsaglia

I would propose to look at [PCG64](https://www.pcg-random.org/), and try to compare your code with it, run the same statistical tests mentioned above, measure speed etc.

Comment: Thank you. I'd love to use PCG, but the sample is very cryptic to me. I wish they simply had implemented a template function using the RNG class, and test it like that.

Comment: @Pippin I'm asking not to use PCG64 (of course, you could use it if you wish), but see how tests for PCG64 are done, how you could adapt them for your RNG and how they are comparable. PCG64 is kind of smallest acceptable (by today norms) RNG, reasonable quality with high speed and small memory usage.